# Subtract two values

Tags: django

I'd like to subtract two values, one in the current record, then the next in the next record...they are time clock entries and I want to calculate the amount of time an employee spend on his/her break, so I'll have to subtract the time the employee clocked out, and the time the employee clocked back in.  This will be done for several records, then at the end of it all I also want to have total of all the breaks taken.

So how can I do this?  I'm doing this in Django BTW.

**UPDATE**
The records look a bit like this:

```
employee_id, rec_date, start_time, end_time
18, 2010-08-23, 09:58:00, 14:13:00
18, 2010-08-23, 14:39:00, 18:47:00
19, 2010-08-23, 14:15:00, 18:31:00
21, 2010-08-23, 12:05:00, 14:52:00
21, 2010-08-23, 15:23:00, 18:49:00
21, 2010-08-31, 08:00:00, 12:00:00
21, 2010-08-31, 12:45:00, 19:00:00
```

Comment: I was at a loss at what to do...so I haven't tried anything...I just have the logic of what I want to do

Comment: Since you say this is based on an external data set, providing a sample set of data would help a lot.

Comment: @Jordan:  I've added a sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to iterate over the clock actions and do the calculation manually. Something of this sort:

```
breaks = 0
break_start = None
clock_actions = user.clock_actions.filter(date=desired_day).order_by('date')
for action in clock_actions:
    if action.type == 'CLOCK IN':
        break_start = action.time
    elif break_start is not None:
        breaks = breaks + action.time - break_start
        break_start = None
```

You may have to adjust the subtraction to work with timedelta objects, depending on your choice of field for time.

Comment: Let me see if this works out...though the records come from an external source and aren't clearly marked as a "Clock In" or "Clock Out"